# ¿Cómo concatenar el nombre de una variable con el de otra?

Tags: python

A ver tengo esta funcion:

```
   def comprobarRespuesta(importe_a, importe_b, importe_c, respuesta):
       opcion_a = "a"
       opcion_b = "b"
       opcion_c = "c"

       if respuesta == opcion_a: return importe_a
       if respuesta == opcion_b: return importe_b
       if respuesta == opcion_c: return importe_c
```

y yo quisiera hacer algo asi:

```
   def comprobarRespuesta(importe_a, importe_b, importe_c, respuesta):

   return opcion_respuesta
```

respuesta es un string que contiene "a","b" o "c".

las variables importe_a, importe_b e importe_c son int.

Comment: no entendí que quieres retornar

Comment: Creo que se la solucion, solo necesito que me aclares algo. Basandome enla primera pieza de codigo, supongo que no es `opcion_x`, sino `importe_x` (donde `x` es cualquiera de `a`, `b` o `c`) lo que quieres retornar verdad? Si no seria bueno que clarificaras un poco mas que es lo que quieres retornar de la funcion.

Comment: yo lo que quiero hacer es tengo 1 pregunta y 3 posibles respuestas, cada una de las respuestas, valen x puntos, que son los importes, entonces yo a la funcion le paso los importes y la respuesta que ha dado el encuestado,  y lo que quiero es, si ha respondido "c" pues quiero que la funcion retorne importe_c, pero claro como hago eso sin usar el if? yo lo que quiero hacer, es que la funcion devuelva el importe que se llama igual que la letra que hay dentro de la variable respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes crear un nombre de variable a partir de cadenas contenidas en otras variables (en realidad en python sí puedes, pero no debes, el código no sería limpio, ver la ampliación de la respuesta más adelante). No obstante puedes lograr lo que buscas de otra forma.

```py
   def comprobarRespuesta(importes, respuesta):
       opciones = "abc"
       return importes[opciones.index(respuesta)]
```

He cambiado los tres parámetros iniciales por uno solo. Quien llame a la función deberá proporcionar una lista con tres elementos para ese primer parámetro. Lo que hacemos luego es seleccionar el elemento apropiado de esa lista, según la posición en que se encuentre `respuesta` dentro de la cadena "abc".

Ejemplo de uso:

```py
>>> comprobarRespuesta([1, 2, 3], "b")
2
```

Naturalmente si en repuesta no va ni "a" ni "b" ni "c" tendrás un error. Puede mejorarse la funcion para que detecte ese caso y retorne algún valor específico.

### El código "sucio"

Solo para que veas que en python se puede hacer, pero no queda muy limpio, proporciono la solución que hace lo que preguntabas "concatenar nombres de variables".

A través de las cadenas de formato podemos crear una cadena que sea el nombre de una variable. Por ejemplo `f"importe_{respuesta}"` dará lugar a la cadena `"importe_a"` si `respuesta` tiene el valor `"a"`.

Esto está bastante cerca de lo que buscas, pero no es suficiente. Aunque hemos creado un nombre de variable, no deja de ser una cadena. No tenemos forma de acceder al dato que hay en la variable con ese nombre (suponiendo que exista una).

Pero ahora viene la segunda parte del truco. Todas las variables de un programa están almacenadas en diccionarios python. Hay uno global para todas las variables globales y otro local para las locales de las funciones (y los parámetros que son un tipo de variable local). Puedes acceder a ese diccionario invocando `globals()` y  `locals()` respectivamente.

Entonces usando `locals()` tendríamos un diccionario cuyas claves son los nombres de variables locales de la función (y sus parámetros). Accediendo en ese diccionario a la clave `"importe_a"` tendríamos el valor de esa variable. Pero `"importe_a"` es la cadena que construimos antes gracias a `f"importe_{respuesta}"`, con lo que ya tenemos todos los ingredientes para la solución:

```py
def comprobarRespuesta(importe_a, importe_b, importe_c, respuesta):
    return locals()[f"importe_{respuesta}"]
```

Demo:

```
>>> comprobarRespuesta(1, 2, 3, "b")
2
```

(Observa que ahora ya no pasamos una lista, sino los parámetros separados por comas).

Comment: No se si te he entendido bien.
yo lo que quiero hacer es tengo 1 pregunta y 3 posibles respuestas, cada una de las respuestas, valen x puntos, que son los importes, entonces yo a la funcion le paso los importes y la respuesta que ha dado el encuestado,  y lo que quiero es, si ha respondido "c" pues quiero que la funcion retorne importe_c, pero claro como hago eso sin usar el if? yo lo que quiero hacer, es que la funcion devuelva el importe que se llama igual que la letra que hay dentro de la variable respuesta.